# SQL query on large table, how to construct a left join using two alias from the same table

Tags: sql, pyspark

No expert on SQL here. I have this huge table and I want to make a join on two alias on that table. For each ID I want the find the value of v1 for it's corresponding ID_relate. ID_relate here could be a persons spouse for example. So on each ID I want the v1 for that specific person and the v1 for it spouse (ID_relate).

Is this a good way to construct a query? I find it becomes a lot of t1. in the where statement below. The original query is more complex that this example I provide below.

Advice would be much appreiciated. Using PySpark.

```
query = '''SELECT t1.ID, t1.ID_relate, t1.country, t1.year, t1.country_relate, t1.v1, t2.id, t2.v1 as value_relate
              from table t1
              LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.ID_relate = t2.id 
              WHERE 
              t1.country in ('USA', 'UK) 
            AND
            t1.year in ('2023') 
             '''
```

Comment: Is this a good way to construct a query? yes.

Comment: @Vulwsztyn Would it make a difference if I did the WHERE before the LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @Henri, no it wouldn't make a difference. Different syntax for the same join construct.

Comment: Then my only problem is the performance of this join. Takes forever.

Comment: For large tables self join will take some time. You could also look into query plan (google how for your dbms), maybe you are lacking index on `ID_relate` or something.